# Speech Recognition Grammar not working with multiple items

Tags: c#, grammar

I have the following grammar, if I remove the line `<item>notepad++</item>` everything functions as expected, but when I add it nothing is recognized. I am working off of the example from the Microsoft site here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.grammar.aspx)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US" mode="voice" root="open"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" tag-format="semantics/1.0">


<rule id="open">
    <item>open <ruleref uri="#progs"/></item>
</rule>

<rule id="progs">
    <item>google <ruleref uri="#googleServices"/></item>
    <item>notepad</item>
</rule>

<rule id="googleServices">
    <one-of>
        <item>inbox<tag>INBOX_URL</tag></item>
        <item>drive<tag>DRIVE URL</tag></item>
        <item>music<tag>MUSIC URL</tag></item>
    </one-of>
</rule>

</grammar>
```

My goal is to say "open notepad" or "open google inbox" and have the grammar respond.

Comment: There is "notepad" in the sample you've provided, but post talks about "notepad++" please make sure this is what you expected to post.

Comment: This is what I expected to post, I have removed the ++. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/) it looks like you need `one-of` to specify that only one `item` should match:

```
<rule id="progs">
  <one-of>
    <item>google <ruleref uri="#googleServices"/></item>
    <item>notepad</item>
  </one-of>
</rule>
```